# Java mail doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I’m using java mail to send automatic mail when a button is pressed.
I work on android studio, and i get the error `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` and I can't find why.

- I tried changing port to 25 - 587 and 465
- Id are correct
- tried on emulator and on real device
- my gmail account is open to low secure application

here is the code :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host" , "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.stmp.user" , "horiond@gmail.com");

        //TLS
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "xxxxx");

        //SSL
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session  = Session.getDefaultInstance( props , null);
        String to = "horiond@gmail.com";
        String from = "horiond@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Testing...";
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText("Working fine..!");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com" , 465  , "horiov@gmail.com", "xxxx");
            transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("fine!!");
        }
        catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
```

Comment: Fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), update your post with the new code, and if it still doesn't work, update your post with the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this link in another question. This should be able to help you.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)